# How to parse string datetime?

Tags: jquery, jsp, datetime, datepicker

I have a date selected from datepicker and also a dropdown list which contains the times.

Is there a way I could overwrite the datepicker with a time whenever user chosen the time?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" />

<select id="ddlDateTime" runat="server" style="display:none;">
     <option value="09:00">Morning</option> 
     <option value="12:00">Lunch</option> 
 </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=txtDateTime.ClientID%>').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function (date) {

            $('#<%=ddlDateTime.ClientID%>').show();
            $('#<%=ddlDateTime.ClientID%>').change(updateDatePicker);
        }
    });

function updateDatePicker()
    {
        var selectedTime = $(this).val();
        var selectedDate = $('#<%=txtDateTime.ClientID%>').datepicker('getDate');

        //how to combine the date and time together?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine them

```
var selectedTime = $(this).val();
var selectedDate = $('#<%=txtDateTime.ClientID%>').datepicker('getDate');    
date = selectedDate + " " + selectedDate ;
```

Then set the `date object` to date picker.

Comment: alert('You have selected ' + selectedDate + ' ' + selectedTime); gives me "You have selected Wed Aug 21 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0930 12:45". I don't know why the date would still gives me 00 time.

Answer (score 0):

Set dateFormat to an empty string

```
$('#<%=txtDateTime.ClientID%>').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: '',
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
```